# Why does 'this' get bound to the window inside the object's closure after backbone's model.fetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, closures, this

So I have this javascript/Backbone script that looks something like this:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({

 initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this); //bind this
   this.doProcessing();
 },

 doProcessing: function() {

  $('.someElement').each(function() {
      Model myModel = new Model;
      myModel.fetch({                          //issue ajax
         success: function(model, response){   //after successful ajax
            console.log(this)                  // <-- outputs Window!!
       });     

   }); //end each

  } //end processing

});

new View;
```

What escapes me is how does `this` get bound to the Window. I'm well aware of my closures but shouldn't `this` refer to the `model`?

Here's what I understand - the success call back is somehow bound to the Window Object. Thus when it's invoked the context is that of the window object. But it's a bit unexpected behaviour in my opinion. Any reason why backbone does it (or am I misunderstanding something?).

It's a bit weird to set the `myModel`'s properties via the `model` parameter of `success`. It seems quite convoluted to call `model.set({...})` when it should allow for a simple `this.set({...})`

Is my understanding of `this` correct in this case? Any workarounds? Or is this more of of the way XHR binds to success callbacks?

From Backbone's source (Model.fetch):

```
fetch: function(options) {
      options = options ? _.clone(options) : {}; //cloning options - does this variable get bound to global?
      var model = this;
      var success = options.success;            //or is it this?
      options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
        if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, xhr), options)) return false;
        if (success) success(model, resp);
      };
      options.error = Backbone.wrapError(options.error, model, options);
      return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the success call back is somehow bound to the Window Object"

No, functions in JavaScript are not "bound". What `this` is is only specified at the time the function is called. Let's see how it is called

```
success(model, resp)
```

So the function is called directly, not through a method call syntax (`someObj.someMethod(...)`), nor through `.call()` or `.apply()`. So in this case, `this` is set to the global object, which in this case is the window.

Answer (score 0):

One work around would be to try something like this

```
myModel.fetch({                          
     success: _.bind(function(model, response){   
        console.log(this);                  
   },this);
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. The output is the div element on which `each` is iterating, but not `myModel`

Comment: works if you change `this` to `myModel` as the last parameter to bind. But isn't this a bit ugly?

Answer (score 0):

This happens by default since .call() or .apply() hasn't given any specific context and it falls back to using `window` as the `this` object

Comment: where do you see that? The call to `call` includes `this` as the context if I understand correctly

Comment: there is no `call` being done... your success handler is just being called regularly: `if (success) success(model, resp);`

Answer (score 0):

The *context* of a block, or what `this` is making reference to is very *volatile* in javascript.

I think the change of context is done in the block `$('.someElement').each(function() { ... });`, and nothing related to how the `Model.fetch()` works.

Try to add more log like:

```
doProcessing: function() {
  console.log( "out of the block", this );

  $('.someElement').each(function() {
    console.log( "begining of block", this );

    Model myModel = new Model;
    myModel.fetch({                          
      success: function(model, response){ 
        console.log( "into the fetch", this );                 
      }     
    });
  };

  console.log( "end of block", this );
}
```

Into the `each` block `this` should be the actual DOM element into the loop.

To solve this change of `this` meaning a workaround that I'm used to use, and that I'm used to see around is referencing `this` to another variable out of the *block* (when `this` is what you expect to be) and use this new reference into the block:

```
doProcessing: function() {
  console.log( "out of the block", this );

  var _self = this;

  $('.someElement').each(function() {
    console.log( "begining of block", _self );

    Model myModel = new Model;
    myModel.fetch({                          
      success: function(model, response){ 
        console.log( "into the fetch", _self );
      }     
    });
  };

  console.log( "end of block", this );
}
```

#### Update

If what you want is make reference to your recent created Model just use the external reference you have created like this:

```
doProcessing: function() {
  $('.someElement').each(function() {
    Model myModel = new Model;
    myModel.fetch({                          
      success: function(model, response){ 
        console.log( "into the fetch", myModel );                 
      }     
    });
  };
}
```

Or just use the reference that Backbone is sending to the *success callback*:

```
doProcessing: function() {
  $('.someElement').each(function() {
    Model myModel = new Model;
    myModel.fetch({                          
      success: function(model, response){ 
        console.log( "into the fetch", model );                 
      }     
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do use that. But that is not the point. `_self` refers to the outermost object and **not** to `myModel`

Comment: @PhD Answer updated to show you how to pass a reference to the recent created Model